# CentOS 5.6 Firewall Script [bad/good practice]

Tags: linux, networking, centos, firewall, iptables

I am currently setting up a new machine with CentOS which is going to host a very large site 1M unique+ per day. Now I know my away around Linux quite a bit, but I have never been the expert when it comes to firewalls and network security. Now I have been handed a script by someone that tightens the security, but I am not sure if this will 'over do' it. I cannot have it that certain users won't be able to visit anymore due to over tight networking rules.

All I need to use it port 80 for http, 443 for https, 21 for ftp and 22 for ssh. I will not run any mail or other services. Just Nginx, vsftpd and ssh.

My question is, can you recommend running all these commands, or only part of them?

The script can be found below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A sample firewall shell script
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
SPAMLIST="blockedip"
SPAMDROPMSG="BLOCKED IP DROP"
SYSCTL="/sbin/sysctl"
BLOCKEDIPS="/root/scripts/blocked.ips.txt"

# Stop certain attacks
echo "Setting sysctl IPv4 settings..."
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians=1
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects=0
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
#$SYSCTL net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_messages=1
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
$SYSCTL net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
$SYSCTL kernel.exec-shield=1
$SYSCTL kernel.randomize_va_space=1

echo "Starting IPv4 Firewall..."
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t mangle -X

# load modules
modprobe ip_conntrack

[ -f "$BLOCKEDIPS" ] && BADIPS=$(egrep -v -E "^#|^$" "${BLOCKEDIPS}")

# interface connected to the Internet
PUB_IF="eth0"

#Unlimited traffic for loopback
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# DROP all incomming traffic
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP

if [ -f "${BLOCKEDIPS}" ];
then
# create a new iptables list
$IPT -N $SPAMLIST

for ipblock in $BADIPS
do
   $IPT -A $SPAMLIST -s $ipblock -j LOG --log-prefix "$SPAMDROPMSG "
   $IPT -A $SPAMLIST -s $ipblock -j DROP
done

$IPT -I INPUT -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I OUTPUT -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I FORWARD -j $SPAMLIST
fi

# Block sync
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW  -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Drop Sync"
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Block Fragments
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -f  -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Fragments Packets"
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -f -j DROP

# Block bad stuff
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "NULL Packets"
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP # NULL packets

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "XMAS Packets"
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP #XMAS

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Fin Packets Scan"
$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP # FIN packet scans

$IPT  -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP

# Allow full outgoing connection but no incomming stuff
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${PUB_IF} -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow http / https (open port 80 / 443)
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -A INPUT -o ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j ACCEPT

# allow incomming ICMP ping pong stuff
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${PUB_IF} -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow port 53 tcp/udp (DNS Server)
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${PUB_IF} -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --destination-port 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT
#$IPT -A OUTPUT -o ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Open port 110 (pop3) / 143
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --destination-port 110 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${PUB_IF} -p tcp --destination-port 143 -j ACCEPT

##### Add your rules below ######
#
#
##### END your rules ############

# Do not log smb/windows sharing packets - too much logging
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -i ${PUB_IF} --dport 137:139 -j REJECT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp -i ${PUB_IF} --dport 137:139 -j REJECT

# log everything else and drop
$IPT -A INPUT -j LOG
$IPT -A FORWARD -j LOG
$IPT -A INPUT -j DROP

exit 0
```

Comment: No hardware firewall?

Comment: Nope that is not available, that is why I want to setup iptables properly.

Comment: This may be a matter of personal taste but 90% of what this script is doing is already done with built-in scripts in CentOS.  You can edit /etc/sysctl.conf which is automatically read on boot and run system-config-securitylevel-tui which edits /etc/sysconfig/iptables and /etc/sysconfig/system-config-securitylevel.  system-config-securitylevel-tui can even be run in a quiet mode to make scripted changes.  Why spend time and effort working on custom scripts instead of configuring software which is already there, which other admins will already know to find.

Comment: umm you're going to host a site that services !M uniques+ per day on ONE SERVER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the RHEL kernel is not the best fit, I would recommend using Shorewall instead of using scripts for firewalling. It is well designed and documented, easy to configure and simple to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Running this:

```
system-config-securitylevel
```

Is probably the simplest way you can go about it. Just specify the ports under the customize menu and you are done. Everything else will be block

However, you probably will have issues with FTP, due to the need for vsFTP to open some of the high ports. Frankly, if you don't need FTP, just disable it. Otherwise, you'll need to configure vsFTP to take into account the firewall.